# fping multiple hosts in parallel

Tags: linux, bash

I want to use fping to ping a number of hosts in parellel and if one is down write it to a file. The below is working but it's running once for each ip how can I eliminate this or have if rcv < 1?

```
#!/bin/bash

down_hosts=/tmp/down.log
hosts=/tmp/ips.txt

while read line  
do
    alive=$(fping -c 1 -f ips.txt | awk -F: '{ print $1 }')
    grep -q -o $line <<<$alive
    if [[ "$?" ==  "1" ]];
    then
        echo "$line is offline"
        if  [ $(grep -c "$line" "$down_hosts") -eq 0 ]; then
            echo $line >> down.log
        fi    
    else
        echo "$line is online"
        if  [ $(grep -c "$line" "$down_hosts") -eq 1 ]; then
            sed -i "/$line/d" "$down_hosts"
        fi
    fi
done < ips.txt
```

Output

```
8.8.8.8 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 1/1/0%, min/avg/max = 3.67/3.67/3.67
1.2.3.4 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 1/0/100%
4.3.2.1 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 1/0/100%
8.8.8.8 is online

8.8.8.8 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 1/1/0%, min/avg/max = 3.68/3.68/3.68
1.2.3.4 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 1/0/100%
4.3.2.1 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 1/0/100%
1.2.3.4 is offline

8.8.8.8 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 1/1/0%, min/avg/max = 3.65/3.65/3.65
1.2.3.4 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 1/0/100%
4.3.2.1 : xmt/rcv/%loss = 1/0/100%
4.3.2.1 is offline
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `fping` invocation does the same each time, you can run it before the loop.

```
alive=$(fping -c 1 -f ips.txt | awk -F: '{ print $1 }')
while read line  
do
    # ...
done < ips.txt
```